# get dns/dhcp address powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, dns, dhcp

Using powershell I would like to return the DNS servers and DHCP address as variables. I have tried the get-DNS cmdlet but powershell doesn't recognize it.

it should return this for ex. 
    $DNS1 = 1.1.1.1
    $DNS2 = 2.2.2.2
    $DHCP = 3.3.3.3

Comment: When you say "DHCP address", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: dhcp server address? I want the address that appears under DHCP Server when you ipconfig, not sure if im using the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

Below command gives you all the Properties of Network Adapter configuration:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select *
```

Using this Inside parenthesis will give you access to the individual properties of the output:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select *)[2].DHCPServer
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select *)[2].DNSServerSearchOrder
```

Here [2] is the index number of the network adapter you are looking at (if you have multiple)